# Ingresar texto de manera dinámica en un WYSIWYG

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, quill

Estoy usando el WYSIWYG Quill, pero resulta que ahora quiero insertar texto en el editor pero sin tenerlo que incluir todo el código escrito en cada página, ya que lo hago con un include, pero no se como agregarle texto desde mi base de datos.
Lo que hago en estos momentos es ingresar este código en cada una de las páginas donde se debe modificar una entrada:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.4/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.4/quill.js"></script>
<div id="toolbar"></div>
    <div id="editor"><?=$entrada_actual['descripcion']?></div>
        
    <script>
        var toolbarOptions = [
            ['bold','italic','underline','strike'],
            [{'align':[]}],
            [{'color':[]}],
            [{'size':['small',false,'large','huge']}],
            ['link','video']
        ];
            
        var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
            modules:{
                toolbar: toolbarOptions
            },
            theme: 'snow'
        });
    </script>
```

y lo que quiero es poder poner por un include y cargar el texto de la base de datos en el editor si alguien sabe como hacerlo, agradeceria mucho que ayudara con esto.

gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Conecta tu base de datos a un archivo php
2. Selecciona la tabla y el id que donde se encuentra el texto
3. Incluye el archivo que conectaste a tu otro archivo (donde esta el editor)
4. En el editor haz: `echo $conx['tabla'];`

Espero que esto te ayude. Suerte

```
<div id="editor">
 `<?php
  echo $tarea['actividades'];
  ?>` 
</div>

`<?php 
   //conexion
   $link = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=het","root","");

   //nombre de la tabla ( en este caso yo utilize un codigo de una pagina que realize 
   //donde hacia el envio post desde un select).
   $materia = $_POST['lista1'];

   //id de la tabla.
   $tp = $_POST['lista2'];

   //selecionar el la tabla e id.
   $tarea = $link->query("SELECT * FROM $materia where id=$tp")->fetch();
 ?>´
```